# Intelij Maven : error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later. Is there anymore solutions?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

I'm trying to install dependendies using `mvn install` but I got thiss error :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.299 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-04-07T23:29:40+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project words-api: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] error: Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried to find solution on stackoverflow but for now I still get same error

What I've tried :

1. Changing level language
   2.Adding properties to pom.xml file

Other solution that I've found involves other type of IDE

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm new to Maven and if you know any solutions tha I haven't tried please comment down below. I will be thankfull for your answers

Edit: I'm using apache.maven.3.8.1

Comment: Does it help if you configure Maven to run on JDK 1.8? In IntelliJ IDEA this is controlled here: https://i.imgur.com/SbuV0a9.png and here https://i.imgur.com/wyh1S8c.png. On your OS/terminal it's controlled via the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. It looks like you run Maven on JDK 11 or later which no longer supports 1.6 targets.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Omg, It's worked. Thank you so much! It's appeared that I didn't even have JDK 1.8 so I installed it and change JAVA_HOME. There were a lot of solution in the stackoverflow that I went though and I never stumbled the solution like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Java 1.8 (JDK) and configure `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to the installation home of this Java version. You may need to logout/login or reboot for the environment variable change to have effect.

Maven will use it for compilation and will be able to target 1.6 version.

Java 11+ versions no longer support 1.6 target.

In IntelliJ IDEA it can be controlled here:

- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | JDK for importer
- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner | JRE

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to use the maven docker image with required jdk
[maven](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven?tab=tags)

1. create the docker volume

```
docker volume create --name maven-repo
```

2. run the maven docker from the root folder of the app

```
docker run --rm -it \
    -v maven-repo:/root/.m2 \
    -v "$(pwd)":/usr/src/mymaven \
    -w /usr/src/mymaven \
    maven:3.2.5-jdk-8 \
    mvn clean install
```